# OpenGL PInvoke call in the finalize causes Access Violation

Tags: c#, opengl, pinvoke

Consider the following code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace GLTest
{
  class Program
  {
    [DllImport("opengl32.dll")]
    protected static extern uint glGetError();

    ~Program()
    {
      GLCall();
    }

    public void GLCall()
    {
      glGetError();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var p = new Program();
      p.GLCall();
    }
  }
}
```

It causes AccessViolationException when GLCall is initiated from ~Program.
Any clues?
OS: Win7 Pro 64

Comment: Well, it looks like the destructor runs too late in the show. I guess you'll need to make sure that the last pinvoke call is made explicitly by you before `Main` completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call OpenGL functions without creating any OpenGL render context before it. There's undefined behavior in the code.

The best practice is:

1. Create a WindowsForm application.
2. Create an OpenGL render context.
3. Call needed OpenGL functions for rendering or another operations.

Comment: You can call `glGetError` without doing any of that. The issue is when the call executes.